# The email address of participant is added to all meetings, not just the one he joined. Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.0

Followed the tutorial on creating meetups and allow participants join them. When adding a participant (his email address) using the form, the email address is added to all meetings, not just the one he joined. I am new to Django, but it seems like the problem is in the ManyToMany relationship.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.address})'


class Participant(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Meetup(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organizer_email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} - {self.slug}'
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Meetup, Participant
from .forms import RegistrationForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    meetups = Meetup.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'meetups/index.html', {
        'meetups': meetups
    })


def meetup_details(request, meetup_slug):
    try:
        selected_meetup = Meetup.objects.get(slug=meetup_slug)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            registration_form = RegistrationForm()
        else:
            registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if registration_form.is_valid():
                user_email = registration_form.cleaned_data['email']
                participant, _ = Participant.objects.get_or_create(email=user_email)
                selected_meetup.participants.add(participant)
                return redirect('confirm-registration', meetup_slug=meetup_slug)

        return render(request, 'meetups/meetup-details.html', {
                'meetup_found': True,
                'meetup': selected_meetup,
                'form': registration_form
            })
    except Exception as exc:
        return render(request, 'meetups/meetup-details.html', {
            'meetup_found': False
        })


def confirm_registration(request, meetup_slug):
    meetup = Meetup.objects.get(slug=meetup_slug)
    return render(request, 'meetups/registration-success.html', {
        'organizer_email': meetup.organizer_email
    })
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your email')
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following? You might want to include a link to it.

Comment: This is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7DrJqcUviA&t=1708s